# Custom Analyzer in Tire (ElasticSearch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying to create this custom analyzer and for some reason I am getting the `Analyzer [] not found for field []` error... I looked around a lot and tried different implementations and I think I have the right syntax for it... Here it is:

```
settings :number_of_shards => 5,
         :number_of_replicas => 2,
         :analysis => {
           :analyzer => {
             :ticker_analyzer => { 
               "type"      => 'custom',
               "tokenizer" => 'ticker_pattern',
               "filter"    => [ 'word_delimiter_filter', 'standard' ]
             }
           },
           :filter => {
             :word_delimiter_filter => {
               "type"                => 'word_delimiter',
               "preserve_original"   => true
             }
           },
           :tokenizer => {
             :ticker_pattern => {
               "type"      => 'pattern',
               "pattern"   => '\w+'
             }
           }
         } do
  mapping do
    # ... some more indexes that work fine, with regular analyzers
    indexes :company_ticker,      type: 'string',   boost: 5.0,   analyzer: 'ticker_analyzer',  as: 'index_company_ticker'
  end
end
```

So I get the error `Analyzer [ticker_analyzer] not found for field [company_ticker]`.

Any ideas why?

Also, I've seen some examples where I won't need to pass a block to the `settings` option. I would just close `settings` and define `mapping` afterwards and it would work? (I've seen this at other people posting code snippets...)

Thank you!

-Vlad

Comment: I followed the model from here: https://github.com/karmi/tire#activemodel-integration  . It doesn't seem to be working for me though... Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this is the *actual* problem that I was having and why this was not working.
It is because I was trying to create an index that would use the mapping from this model (I was not trying to do Model.create_elasticsearch_index) but with something like

```
index = Tire::Index.new('swap_index')
index.create(:mappings => MyModel.tire.mapping_to_hash)
index.import(mymodel_entries)
# and then do some swapping between the old index and the new one, through alias'es
```

Well, the problem was that I was not passing the `settings` to my new index. I was only passing it the `mappings` from the MyModel, but not the `settings`. So, the right way to do it si this

```
index.create(:settings => MyMode.tire.settings, :mappings => MyModel.tire.mapping_to_hash)
```

and this solves the error I was getting.

(My example still does not work in my case because the analyzer might be broken for my case, but I just wanted to help users that might have a similar problem)

Thank you,
Vlad